# Find the leading-order asymptotic approximation without using integration by part

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

How to calculate the following asymptotic approximation without using integration by part:

$$I(x) = \int_0^1 t^x \cos^n(\pi t)dt, \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ x \rightarrow \infty$$

Note: $n$ is an integer.

I try to do the following:

$$I(x) = \int_0^1 \ln e^{t^x} \cos^n(\pi t)dt, \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ x \rightarrow \infty$$

And then I have no idea to go further; how to transform it to use Gaussian integral?  Please advise, thanks!

Comment: @DionelJaime yes $x>0$.

Comment: @DionelJaime It is said $x \to \infty$ so $x>0$

Comment: Hint: $t^x = e^{ln(t^x)}=e^{xln(t)}$

Comment: What is the motivation of "without using integration by part"?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Because I want to try another method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may try this path.

First of all exponentiate the cosine:

$$\cos^n(\pi t) = \left(\frac{e^{i\pi t} + e^{-i\pi t}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2^n}\left(e^{i\pi t} + e^{-i\pi t}\right)^n$$

Then use the Binomial Series to expand the power

$$\left(e^{i\pi t} + e^{-i\pi t}\right)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}e^{ik\pi t} e^{-i\pi t(n-k)} = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} e^{i\pi t(2k - n)}$$

Put all together and you have

$$\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_0^1 t^x e^{i\pi t(2k - n)}\ \text{d}t$$

By calling $\alpha = \pi(2k-n)$ we recognize a well known integral:

$$\int t^x e^{i\alpha t}\ \text{d}t = \frac{e^i t^x (-\alpha t)^{-x} \Gamma (x+1,-\alpha t)}{\alpha}$$

Integrating it from $0$ to $1$ yields

$$e^i \pi ^{-x-1} (n-2 k)^{-x-1} (\Gamma (x+1)-\Gamma (x+1,(n-2 k) \pi ))$$

Putting all together:

$$e^i\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{1}{\pi ^{x+1}}  \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(n-2 k)^{x+1}} (\Gamma (x+1)-\Gamma (x+1,(n-2 k) \pi ))$$

By some knowledge about asymptotic expansion, you can show that around infinity:

$$\Gamma (x+1)-\Gamma (x+1,(n-2 k) \pi ) \sim \frac{\left[\pi (n - 2k)\right]^{x+1}}{x}e^{2k\pi - n\pi}$$

So using this we arrive at

$$e^i\frac{1}{2^n} \frac{e^{-\pi n}}{x}\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}  e^{2kn} (n-2k)^{x+1}$$